# Abstracting out existence of service bus/distributed messaging?

Tags: c#, .net, soa, abstraction, servicebus

I'm working on a system right now that is in a single process space; we are breaking this up into several processes, initially to run on the same box but ultimately to distribute across several separate machines.  I'm leaning towards using an ESB (NServiceBus, Rhino ESB) or possibly rolling my own with WCF + queues to handle the pub/sub and request/response scenarios our app has.

However, I'm struggling with the abstraction: I don't want the various components to know they are talking over the bus.  The current APIs connecting the various services translate pretty well to this kind of model, but I want to hide that from the client and server sides.  Short of writing a lot of custom proxy code for the client and server, is there a better way to approach this?  I realize WCF can auto-generate proxies based on the service definition, but I really like some of the other stuff I get with (say) rhino servicebus.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to swap out different implementations (with and without an ESB/messaging layer) just using IoC (knowing there would have to be limits enforced by convention on what can be passed across the interfaces), but I'm not sure where to go with that.  I'd really prefer to not have to change every method call on the current interfaces into its own discrete message class, either.

Any resources/patterns/tools to help me do this?  Please ask questions if I'm not clear.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be one solution/off-the-shelf component that might help you.

**Problem 1:**
The basic problem can be solved via an ESB, as it provides *location transparency* and *service aggregation*. A regular ESB **mediates/brokers** requests between service consumer and service provider.
Take a simple example:

> ```
> Service_A     depends on      Service_B  
> Service_C     depends on      Service_B  
> Service_B     depends on      Service_D
> ```

In this scenario, the best way to progress is this:

1. Define contracts exposed by `Service_B` and `Service_D` as *external dependencies* (possibly as a web service, though an ESB supports multiple protocols) in services `Service_A`, `Service_C` and `Service_B`, and consume via an ESB.
2. In ESB, to start with, route thes services `Service_B` and `Service_D` on the same instance.
3. If you migrate `Service_D` and `Service_B` as `Service_Dx` and `Service_Bx` on a different location, the ESB can be reconfigured to route to the new location. Also, an ESB can be configured to route to `Service_B` or `Service_Bx` based on some set of parameters (eg., test data to `Service_B` and production data to `Service_Bx`)

**Problem 2:**
The problem of IOC could probably be hard to achieve; there may not be a need.
I presume the clients, instead of consuming from a known location, are injected with the whereabouts of service location. This in reality transfers the configuration to client side. With this, for every new client added to the system there needs to be a separate configuration control. This might lead to logistical issues.

*Please post your final solution, very interested to know your approach.*

Comment: Just as a follow-up -- this part of my project got tabled and is still that way.  If/when we pick it back up, I'll follow up.

Comment: @Joe, Unfortunately, every day more and more large SOA-tools/ESB based enterprise projects are tabled. Not good sign: indicates lack of funds in IT departments...